# Why are all my adress bar suggestions disappeared in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, history, autocomplete, browser-cache, address-bar

When you have ever visited a site in Google Chrome, it saves the URL as a suggestion for auto-complete.
For example: I've ever visited *youtube.com* and since then I can just type the `y` in the adress bar, and Chrome automatically completes it to *youtube.com*

The problem is that sometimes, approximately every 2 months, all suggestions are disappeared as if they are deleted.
I'm quite sure it doesn't happen at regular or sheduled times that all suggestions get deleted. I also do not delete the browser cache, but maybe it get's deleted by a virus scanner?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run CCleaner or any applications alike?

Sign into your Google account on Chrome to save profile settings/user history that should prevent this issue from happening.

Comment: I do not run any program like CCleaner.

Comment: Ok. Is your Google Account logged in on Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If you press Ctrl + Shift + Del button opens a screen through which you are able to remove parts from your browser.

Do not show suggestions for visited pages history is deleted.

This can be done by programs like CCleaner is a system optimization.
Probably one similar to it in your system.